# create-react-app webpack configuration file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

I have created a new react app using `npx create-react-app` and now I want to integrate a `webpack.config.js` file. I know I don't have to but it is a necessary step for an assignment.
I have tried many tutorials an articles but I can't seem to make it work. All I need is to include all the css related loaders (sass, css etc) and babel.

This is my webpack.config.js file:

```
 const path = require('path');


module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: path.join(__dirname,'./src/index.js'),
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
              loader: "babel-loader"
            }
          },
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          "style-loader",
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          "css-loader",
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          "sass-loader"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname,'public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
},
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname,'public')
  }
};
```

And I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 7:16
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (7:16)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
| 
> ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
| 
| // If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
```

Comment: If you want to customize the webpack [https://medium.com/@ryoldash/customize-webpack-config-of-react-app-created-with-create-react-app-7a78c7849edc](https://medium.com/@ryoldash/customize-webpack-config-of-react-app-created-with-create-react-app-7a78c7849edc) follow this tutorial.

Comment: If you add external css, sass etc... import the file from index.js like `import "styles.css";`, then copy the `style.css` paste to ``public` folder.

Comment: I have seen this article but it didn't solve my problem. I have updated the info

Answer (score 1):

There're some alternatives that can override webpack config without ejecting the CRA project:

> Alternatives You can try [customize-cra](https://github.com/arackaf/customize-cra) for a set of CRA 2.0 compatible
>   rewirers, or any of the alternative projects and forks that aim to
>   support 2.0:
>
> 1. [Rescripts](https://github.com/harrysolovay/rescripts), an alternative framework for extending CRA configurations
>      (supports 2.0+).
> 2. [react-scripts-rewired](https://github.com/marcopeg/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/README.md) for a fork of this project that
>      aims to support CRA 2.0
> 3. [craco](https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco)

Answer (score 0):

add `config-overrides.js` in the route and add your webpack changes as:

```
const { addWebpackModuleRule } = require('customize-cra')

module.exports = {
  webpack: override(
    addWebpackModuleRule({
      issuer: {
        test: /\.sass?$/,
      },
      loader: 'file-loader',
      test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
    }))
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Answering this just because it kills me to see 10 page Medium articles as an answer when it can be answered in 1 sentence.

Enter your project dir and run `npm run eject`

This will extract all of the configuration files for you to edit, including webpack.config.js, to a folder called "config". Enter config/webpack.config.js, find the "return" statement, and inside there is a "resolve" configuration option. Add the following to that object:

```
symlinks: false
```

Boom. Saved you a stupidly long Medium article.

Comment: You might want to mention that ejecting is irreversible, and that when you eject you're completely on your own, having to do a full setup of webpack, webpack configuration and perhaps some different folders/file paths here and there.

Comment: This is completely untrue. It extracts all of the configuration for you and allows you to edit it, but if it already works, it won't break your existing configuration. You don't have to do anything extra.

Comment: You will if the CRA team comes out with updates you'd like to take advantage of without having to do everything manually on your own, which is one of the big "selling points" of CRA